# Place HTML5 Radio Buttons in a Horizontal Line

Tags: html, css

I want to align two radio buttons and their labels in a horizontal line
but the Chrome browser pushes the second radio button and label to the next line. Below is the code:

```
<li>
    <p> 
        <label for="request" id="officallabel">Purpose</label> 
        <input type = "radio"
            name = "approvalbuttons"
            id = "approved"
            value = "Approved"
    <label for = "approved">Approved</label>

    <input type = "radio"
            name = "approvalbuttons"
            id = "denied"
            checked = "checked" 
            value = "denied" />
    <label for = "denied">Denied</label>
    </p>
</li>
```

The CSS code

```
input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your CSS also.

Comment: is something in your css, by default they are in line

Comment: It should be noted that the the first input is **not closed**

Answer (score 2):

You have the following **errors**:

1. You cannot nest anything like form elements inside `<p>` tag. Replace it with a `<div>` tag.
2. You haven't closed the `<input />`.

Use this **snippet**:

```html
<li>
  <div> 
    <label for="request" id="officallabel">Purpose</label> 
    <input type = "radio"
           name = "approvalbuttons"
           id = "approved"
           value = "Approved" />
    <label for = "approved">Approved</label>

    <input type = "radio"
           name = "approvalbuttons"
           id = "denied"
           checked = "checked" 
           value = "denied" />
    <label for = "denied">Denied</label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: yes i agree with you on the corrections thank you. Run your code in my browser but i have a lot of space between the radio buttons and the labels. Is there a way to reduce the distance between the label and the radio button.

Comment: @faisalabdulai Lot of space? Nopes, not here. What's your screen resolution?

Comment: the screen resolution is 1366 x 768

Comment: Same with mine. But yeah... You can reduce by, *need to think*. Will update the answer soon!

Comment: let me say that i have divided the page into sections and article could that be the reason why second radio button and label are in the second line

Comment: Yeah, that could be too!

Comment: There is no closing slash for the input element. Though you can do it, it's pointless, and ignored.

Comment: @Rob OP didn't even close it!

Comment: You speak `HTML` and I speak `XML / XHTML`! `:)`